# How to fix issues in eventRender and resourceRender functions of FullCalendar v4.x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using the `eventRender` and `resourceRender` function in the same FullCalendar declaration.

I used this code in the `resourceRender` function:

```
info.el.querySelector(".fc-cell-text").append(questionMark);
```

But I faced this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

In innerHTML()function, the same issue happens.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem just based on the info you have provided. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGBaBjM . It works perfectly. So please, if you still need help, can you provide enough code which would show this issue occurring? You can fork my CodePen if you like, and change it to be more like your code, and make it show the problem. I can't help you fix your issue if I can't make it occur in the code.

Comment: I'm  not sure why you are giving that ID? This is a public website. If you ask a question here, it will be answered here, in the website, for the benefit of everyone. We don't do private consultations. You can either provide the information I asked for, so that we can help you. Or you can try to solve it yourself. It's up to you. If you want to find someone who will fix it privately for you, go to a website where you can hire a programmer for money. Thanks.